# Owl Carousel center slide with particular class

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Going by Owl Carousel docs, you can use `to.owl.carousel` to navigate to a particular slide.

I have a thumbnail carousel running across the top of the page, which I have added a class to items that are the current page (class is called `thisPatient`).

I'd like to use the center carousel, and have it so that the carousel item that has the `thisPatient` class, is centred on page load. How can this be done?

I have noticed that `to.owl.carousel` requires the ID of a slide to navigate to, but I need to convert this to get the ID of the slide with the particular class applied.

Example of this can be seen at development.bellavou.co.uk/patient-stories/allison

This is currently what I have:

```
$(".patient-story-strip").owlCarousel({
    dots:false,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    stagePadding:50,
    lazyLoad:true,
    center:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{items:3},
        768:{items:9},
        1200:{items:13}
    }
});
```

Comment: If you add   var start = $('.thisPatient').index(); and have startPosition: start as one of the owlCarousel options, does it center that slide or have it left aligned?

Comment: Neither, it seems to leave the carousel fixed when navigating to other profiles

Comment: [Codepen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aJoYVa) I have it working here - does something like this work for you?

Comment: With some small adjustments to classes, yes that seem to work. Awesome. LEave that as an answer and I'll mark it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var start = $('.patientInfo').index();
    $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
        dots:false,
        loop:true,
        items: 13,
        startPosition: start,
        center:true,
        responsive:{
            0:{items:3},
            768:{items:9},
            1200:{items:13}
    }});
});
```

Since the startPosition uses a 0-index like the index() function, starting at that number and centering it makes the carousel function like you were aiming for.